# How to make an array of integer arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I have been trying to make an array of integer arrays. I know that the outer array will have length N whilst every integer array within in only needs to hold two values.

Originally, I made an ArrayList with an Integer array:

```
int[] intArray = new int[2];
ArrayList<IntArray> outerArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then proceeded to just make an ArrayList of Integer within another ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outerArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm looking for something that looks like this if N = 3 and a,b,c are integers:

{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}

Comment: `int[][] array = int[n][2];` ? You can then access, for example, `array[1][0]`

Comment: `Integer[][]`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int[][] array = new int[10][10];
```

And you wrote something like this :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

This is not an array, but list. You might read this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this I think.

```
final int n = 5;
Integer[][] ints = new Integer[n][2];
```